# Override base URL on angular httpclient get request

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, get, request

I'm trying to make a get request to a certain URL but it seems to be replaced to another one,this resulting in making a get request to an non-existant URL.

Here is my code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ApitestProvider {
  tests;
  apiUrl = "http//:localhost:8000/api";
  testAdded;
  testGotten;
  testDeleted;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

    console.log('Hello ApitestProvider Provider');
  }

  getTests() {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/tests").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.testGotten = data;
    }), err => {
      console.log(err);
    }

  }
```

but it ends up making a request for the following URL

```
url: "http://localhost:8100/http//:localhost:8000/api/tests"
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an interceptor?

Comment: You can check your _base url_ in your `index.html` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have incorrectly typed your API URL.

instead of this: `apiUrl = 'http//:localhost:8000/api';`

it should be this: `apiUrl= 'http://localhost:8000/api';`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bitee)